# Help with getting an older WinTV-PVR-150 to work in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: media, capture

I admit I am completely new and green to the world of capture cards.  At the moment, Id only like to view the stream coming from my old VCR as opposed to recording anything (for now).  The VCR is confirmed working with my regular TV, hooked through AV cords. But when I try and use VLC, all I get is screen static.

This is how I get what little I have.

Open VLC
Open Capture Device
Under Capture Mode, the one I can get to show something is 'Video for Linux 2'
Video Device Name: /dev/video32 is the only one that will show anything. Running either video0 or video24 causes VLC to close
Audio device name: hw0:0
Video Standard: NTSC (though I tried undefined and got the same thing)

..and with this, all I get is static, as Ive said.  Im at a loss and could really use pointers from someone who has experience with these cards.

Answer (score 1):

Open with VLC with the pvr command, i.e. 
`vlc pvr:// :pvr-channel=2`

The pvr-channel= option can accept a 0, 1, or 2.
Usually 0 is coax, 1 is s-video, and 2 is av.

Right now, my problem is that I can't get audio in for watching

on my wintv 150, so good luck.